Combining Variation and Uncertainty from Replicate measurements
I have 3 measurements from 3 independent experiments {m_1, m_2, m_3}.
I have another 3 measurements that are used to scale the m measurements {n_1, n_2, n_3} from the same experiment (different from m). As they are from the same experiment, I can determine the uncertainty as the (std.dev.(n) / root(n)).
The n measurements are used to scale m as (m / n).
I want to integrate both the variation and the uncertainty to express the m/n as m/n +- variation. Is this possible? If so how?
I've found a guide to combine sources of uncertainty through "relative quadrature" in Section 5 of: https://phas.ubc.ca/~phys109/manual/UncertaintyFinish/Uncertainty.pdf
But in my limited understanding, variation and uncertainty are determined differently and so it wouldnt make sense to use "relative quadrature"
Thank you!
